# A design update is coming!

Tags: discussion, design

You may have noticed some updates to the design lately, they are part of a SE network-wide update to a new base css framework.

The updates allow us to:

- Have sharper / more beautiful design on retina displays
- Fix layout bugs
- More easily add new features to all of our sites in the future

> **But more importantly, it gives you access [to the new profile](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/current)!**

If you see any bugs please let us know in the form of answers (to this post) that illustrate one particular thing at a time.

Thanks!

Comment: Where "recent" is 8 months ago.

Comment: @RossRidge: no, "recent" apparently means "one week in the future". I can't quite place my finger on what exactly changed, but the front page looks quite different today than it did yesterday.

Comment: @Marti No, I was commenting on the original version of this post, where the word "recent" was used in connection with an event that happened 8 months ago. This post, both old and new versions, is just a mindless copy and paste of a post first made 8 months ago.

Comment: Copy and paste? Probably; these have been the tools of a designer's trade since time immemorial. But *mindless?* If you could see Stéphane sweating over the paste-pot, his brow furrowed in concentration, the blade in hand rock-steady while seemingly every sinew trembles around it... You would not say mindless.

Comment: "A design update has come!"

Comment: *Ping!* Ideas (that happen to be mine...) seem popular (from upvotes) but as yet unaddressed. Are these sufficiently "bugs" or "important" or clear enough? Just a friendly query.

Answer (score 8):

I'm still getting used to the new site design, but I immediately notice one tangible difference that I don't care for: **When browsing questions in the [expanded questions view](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions), it is no longer possible to tell if the question has an *accepted* answer.** It *does* still render differently on the [main title-only view](http://cooking.stackexchange.com), but that difference seems arbitrary and I suspect it's a bug. I, personally, always browse the /questions view because it's far more usable to me.

Currently, the rendering of "one or more answers" and "an answer has been accepted" is identical in the main questions-only view. I *think* it used to be that black text showed 0 answers, green text showed 1-or-more answers, and a green background that looked like a green outline of a "covered platter," which I always thought was clever. Compare, for example, accepted answer rendering at [the "default" design at Coffee.SE main page](http://coffee.stackexchange.com) versus the [expanded page](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions) -- both Coffee.SE views render "accepted answer questions" consistently.

I am not sure if this is intentional, or if this is The New Way for the SE network as a whole, but regardless of rendering **I prefer the "distinguishability" of questions with an accepted answer.**

Answer (score 4):

So votes can be cast separately and addressed independently, I refactored my other answer.

The "accepted answer" rendering used to be the outline of a covered platter. I always thought this was a rather clever cartoon-y rendering of the fact that the meal had concluded. In [the main site view](http://cooking.stackexchange.com), the current rendering of answered-but-not-accepted is green text; the current rendering of an-answer-has-been-accepted is a simple filled-in lime-green circle.

**I prefer the "covered platter" answered-question background** as in the previous design, over the simple "circle" rendering as it currently is.